# React Native - Error while initialising new project

Tags: react-native, npm, npm-install

I am getting following error when I try to run command

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve npm ERR!
> npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined npm ERR! Found:
> react-native@0.68.2 npm ERR! node_modules/react-native npm ERR!   peer
> react-native@"*" from @react-native-community/cli@7.0.3 npm ERR!
> node_modules/@react-native-community/cli npm ERR!
> @react-native-community/cli@"^7.0.3" from react-native@0.68.2 npm ERR!
> react-native@"0.69.0" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Could
> not resolve dependency: npm ERR! react-native@"0.69.0" from the root
> project npm ERR! npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.0.0
> npm ERR! node_modules/react npm ERR!   peer react@"18.0.0" from
> react-native@0.69.0 npm ERR!   node_modules/react-native npm ERR!
> react-native@"0.69.0" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix the
> upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with
> --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm ERR! See
> C:\Users\NIMASHA NAIK\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for
> a full report.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> C:\Users\NIMASHA
> NAIK\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2022-06-23T13_40_58_714Z-debug-0.log

Please can anyone help?

Thank You.

Comment: This answer fixed it for me.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/72849423/10941

Answer (score 26):

Removing the ~/.npm cache folder worked for me

`rm -r ~/.npm`

Comment: rm: /Users/anastasiia/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/59/e0: Permission denied

There's no input for password or something else. How to fix it?

Comment: @glushkina1 for me on a (non-M1) Mac `sudo rm -rf  ~/.npm` solved the issue you refer to

Comment: where is `~/.npm cache` in windows

Comment: Removing ~/.npm folder worked for me!

Comment: Doing this worked for me. Recommended to use Sudo before the command.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem so I did it

```
npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
npx react-native
```

try it worked.

Answer (score 3):

npm add react-native@0.69.0

Run this command to upgrade react-native. Hope it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Are you able to post the full log found in your AppData?

You could also try completely removing node.js from your system and try reinstalling it again.

> https://nodejs.org/en/

Install the LTS version and try this again. Also make sure npm and npx are both working in your working directory PATH.

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue in node which is caused by white space in user name between first-name and last-name in windows.

run the following command after replacing firstname with your windows user firstname in command prompt with administrator access

npm config set cache "C:\Users\Firstname~1\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache" --global